# Loop does not terminate for guessing game in JS

Tags: javascript, html

In the prompt, my loop should terminate when the end user types "magenta". It currently does not. What am I missing? I know this is a very basic color guessing game that I plan to expand upon, but I wanted to first fix this before I continue with some enhancements....thanks!

```js
var target = "magenta";
var guess_input_text;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;

function do_game() {

    alert("The correct color is " + target + "!");

    while (!finished) {
        guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n"+
                                  "blue, cyan, gold, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white\n\n"+
                                  "What is the color I am thinking of?");
        guess_input = guess_input_text.toLowerCase();
  finished = check_guess();
    }
}

function check_guess() {

    if (guess_input = "blue") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "cyan") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "gold") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "gray") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "green") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "orange") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "red") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = "white") {
        return false;
    }
    if (guess_input = target) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is "equal to"

Comment: You could simplify the whole function to `function check_guess() { return guess_input === target; }`. Or get rid of it and directly do the comparison in the loop: `while (guess_input !== target) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the comparisons should be made with == (coercing the type) or preferably === (without coercing the type).

So try to just replace your if conditions for:

```
if (guess_input === "blue") { ...
```

Comment: What you ended up doing here is assigning different values to the var ```guess_input``` inside the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not comparing ... you are actualy giving a value here:

```
guess_input = "white"
```

the if statement should be like that:

```
if(guess_input == "white") {
    // your code here inside
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target = "magenta";
var guess_input;

function do_game() {
    //Prompts and makes the answer lowercase.
    guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n"+
                              "blue, cyan, gold, gray, green, magenta, orange, red, white\n\n"+
                              "What is the color I am thinking of?").toLowerCase();

    //Checks if the guess_input equals the target...
    if (guess_input == target) {
        alert("You are correct! The answer is " + target + "!");
    } else {//Not equals target...
        alert("You are incorrect! The correct answer is " + target + "!");
    }
}

do_game();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements contain assignment operators. When checking, you are assigning variables:

```
if(guess_input = "blue") {
    //...
}
```

If you want to compare strings, you should use:

```
if(guess_input === "blue") {
    //...
}
```

Using three equal signs ensures that they are the same type. If you just want to compare values and not types, use two:

```
if(guess_input == "blue") {
    //...
}
```

Note that there are certainly easier ways to check. The simplest being the switch statement:

```
switch(guess_input){
    case "blue":
    case "cyan":
    case "gold":
    case "grey":
    //...
    case "white":
        return false;
    case target:
        return true;
}
```

However, note that this will not return a value when the string does not match any of them (i.e. they enter "yellow").

My recommendation would be only to test if the user input is, in fact, correct. If it is not, return false.

```
if(guess_input == target){
    return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you all...the comparison versus assigning mistake was the culprit

Comment: Yes, but there are several other mistakes or inefficient parts. Focus on errors that don't crash your program, too.